# 100% width images on horizontal scrolling page

Tags: css, image, width, horizontal-scrolling

I'm trying to make a page for a photo story - it's meant to scroll horizontally, but I also want images to scale to 100% height and auto width (so no cropping). The horizontal scroll and 100%  height/auto width is no problem. But I can't get the images spaced properly - they keep overlapping. See: https://i.stack.imgur.com/iAIXT.jpg

Is this possible? Have been working at this for ages and am running out of ideas.

Thanks!

JS:

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    $(function(){
            $(".image").wrap("<td>");
    });
</script>
```

CSS:

```
.image {
position:absolute;
width:auto;
height:100%;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="page-wrap">
         <div class="image">
              <img src="images/Betty-001.jpg" id="image-contents" />  
         </div>

         <div class="image" style="margin-left:75%;">
               <img src="images/Betty-001.jpg" id="image-contents" />  
         </div>             
</div>
```

Comment: post your code so we can see what the problem might be

Answer (score 4, accepted):

HTML will do the scrolling and the image width for you if you let it.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ThinkingStiff/sVa7S/

HTML:

```html
<div id="scroll">
       <img src="http://thinkingstiff.com/images/priorities.png" /><!--
    --><img src="http://thinkingstiff.com/images/priorities.png" />
</div>
```

CSS:

```css
#scroll {
    height: 100%;
    overflow-x: scroll;    
    white-space: nowrap;
    width: 100%;
}

#scroll img {
    height: 100%;
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

Comment: !!! That's it. Thank you so much. This has been driving me crazy all day. Hugely appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following CSS:

```
html, body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

div {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

#image1 {
    background-image: url('image1');
}
#image2 {
    left: 100%;
    background-image: url('image2');
}
#image3 {
    left: 200%;
    background-image: url('image3');
}
#image4 {
    left: 300%;
    background-image: url('image4');
}​
```

using background images with 100% width and 100% height.

You can see a live example of it working [here](http://jsfiddle.net/WWUcD/5/)

Comment: Thank you so much. That's almost exactly what I'm trying to do - I was hoping to have the images re-size to the same ratio. Setting background-size to auto 100% works, but then the white space between images is wrong (see http://jsfiddle.net/WWUcD/3/). Is there a way around that? Thanks!

Comment: You can use background-repeat: no-repeat; look at this example http://jsfiddle.net/WWUcD/5/. Not sure why it works, but it does, so who's complaining!

Comment: Thank you! I'll use that for the cover page - that's perfect. Huge thanks.